# MySQL error pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql ': not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I would like to add pandas df into my sql db. I tried:

```
self.connection = mysql.connect(
                user=config["knihy"]["user"],
                passwd=config["knihy"]["password"],
                host=config["knihy"]["host"],
                db=config["knihy"]["database"],
            )

my_df.to_sql("KNIHY", self.connection, if_exists="append", index=False)
```

but I got an error:

> pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': not all arguments converted during string formatting

I tried the solution here: ["not all arguments converted during string formatting" when to_sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55822497/not-all-arguments-converted-during-string-formatting-when-to-sql)

but this did not help me:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://user:password@localhost/database')
my_df.to_sql("KNIHY", self.connection, if_exists="append", index=False)
self.connection.commit()
```

my_df looks like this:

```
my_df.dtypes

[15 rows x 9 columns]
book_url            object
book_id             object
book_name           object
book_author         object
book_rating         object
book_reviews        object
book_year           object
book_description    object
book_genre          object
dtype: object
```

What do I do wrong, please?

Comment: you need to provide the code for `my_df`

Comment: @eshirvana is dtypes enough? see my edit please